# Using multiple orderBy in Firestore with startAt/endAt is not giving any results

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to order my docs by date and search by **text** as follows

```
db
   .collection(AppConstants.usersCollectionPath)
   .doc(currentUserId)
   .collection(AppConstants.chatsCollectionPath)
   .orderBy('last_time', descending: true)
   .orderBy('search_field')
   .startAt([queryText]).endAt(
  ['$queryText\uf8ff'],
).withConverter<ChatModel>(
  fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
    return ChatModel.fromDocument(snapshot.data()!, snapshot.id);
  },
  toFirestore: (state, __) => state.toJson(),
)
```

but I get the following error:

> chats order by -last_time, search_field, **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here

I followed the link and created the suggested index then the error gune but the query returns empty result.

what am I doing wrong? and how to solve my issue?

**edit**:

This code works as expected searching functionality is working fine

```
result= db
   .collection(AppConstants.usersCollectionPath)
   .doc(currentUserId)
   .collection(AppConstants.chatsCollectionPath)
   .orderBy('search_field')
   .startAt([queryText])
   .endAt(['$queryText\uf8ff'])
   .withConverter<ChatModel>(
     fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
    return ChatModel.fromDocument(snapshot.data()!, snapshot.id);
  },
    toFirestore: (state, __) => state.toJson(),
);
```

But when add `.orderBy('last_time', descending: true)` not working

**Based** on Frank's answer I updated my query like this but it is still resulting empty:

```
 result= db
   .collection(AppConstants.usersCollectionPath)
   .doc(currentUserId)
   .collection(AppConstants.chatsCollectionPath)
   .orderBy('search_field')
   .where('search_field', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: [queryText])
   .where('search_field', isLessThanOrEqualTo: ['$queryText\uf8ff'])
   .orderBy('last_time', descending: true)
   .withConverter<ChatModel>(
  fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
    return ChatModel.fromDocument(snapshot.data()!, snapshot.id);
  },
  toFirestore: (state, __) => state.toJson(),
);
```

Comment: sometimes creating the index takes some time until it is created, check on your console if it is completed. Can you also show us the last part structure of your db side?

Comment: If you have successfully created the index, then are you sure you have documents in the database that satisfy that query? Can you please edit your question and add a concrete example?

Comment: I created the index successfully and now enabled and I have more docs. please see my full query: the index contains search_field,last_time and "\_\_name\_\_"

Answer (score 0):

If you use `startAt`/`endAt` with a list of values, the values in that list must match the `orderBy` clauses of your query. From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAt.html):

> The values must be in order of `orderBy` filters.

You have there `orderBy` clauses:

```
.orderBy('last_time', descending: true)
.orderBy('search_field')
```

Given that, the first value that you pass to `startAt`/`endAt` should be a `last_time` value, and the second one should be a `search_field`. You're not passing a value for `last_time` and only pass a value for `search_field`, which the database then actually tries to match against the `last_time` values in the database. And since that comparison never finds a match, you get no results.

It's probably easier to use `where` condition to accomplish this scenario. The equivalent that way would be:

```
.where('searchField', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: queryText)
.where('searchField', isLessThanOrEqualTo: '$queryText\uf8ff'),
```

Comment: I updated the question using these where clauses but the result is same as start and end

Comment: Ah yeah, on a where the values should not be an array anymore. I updated my answer.

Comment: Have you tried sorting docs by date and at the same time searching by text? because I couldn't make it work. ordering by last_time only is working and searching by search_field only is working but when combined nothing works.